# Why was Luke surprised that Obi-Wan had fought in the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, luke-skywalker, obi-wan-kenobi

In *Star Wars IV: A New Hope*, Luke sounds surprised to learn that Obi-Wan fought in the Clone Wars. I haven’t watched it recently, but I think he even said, “…but that was so long ago!?”

But according to the prequels, the Clone Wars lasted at least until Luke’s birth. So we’re talking about 20 years - not a lot of time at all!?

Comment: Probably Obi-Wan was originally supposed to be a lot older than he looked, like Yoda.

Comment: Remember, Luke just thought he was an old hermit, not a Jedi Knight.

Comment: fwiw - he didn't say 'that was so long ago' - you are probably thinking of his response 'It's all such a long way from here'

Comment: @NKCampbell No, I definitely recall Luke saying something to that effect. I wonder if they cut that line from the later 'improved' editions because it veered from the narrative of the prequels.

Comment: @Woody I've seen every version and own almost every VHS, DVD, and Blu-Ray release (although I was very young when I saw the original theatrical version) and I don't recall that line as your remember it.

Comment: `the Clone Wars lasted at least until Luke's birth` techicianlly Darth Vader (still in the human body of Anikan Skywalker) ended the Clone Wars before Luke's birth when he killed the Separatist leaders on Mustafar, which was probably hours before Luke & Leia's birth.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I just googled it and found the quote as I remember it in the original 'star wars' book - and I did read the original book many years ago, so maybe that's where I'm getting it from. So I guess according to what you're saying it was dropped from the movie and it's not canon?

Comment: @Woody possibly.  I never read the novelizations of the movies so it might have been phrased as you remembered there.  But it was never mentioned in the movies as you described to the best of my recollection.  And it has been mentioned before that Obi-Wan was not nearly as old as he looked.  Alec Guinness was 56 during filming of Episode 4, which is only slightly older than Obi-Wan's actual age based on the timeline established by the prequels.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm not so sure it's a novelization of the movie, as it was written by George Lucas himself in 1976, so it seems to have predated the movie and perhaps the movie was supposed to be based on it.

Comment: @Woody Actually, the novelization was ghostwritten by [Alan Dean Foster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Dean_Foster)

Comment: In the same scene Leia's hologram says that Kenobi "served her father in the Clone Wars".  So it is unlikely that Luke expected the Clone Wars were centuries ago.  It is probably just personal perspective.

Comment: @Skooba Luke didn't show any surprise when Obi-Wan told him (Luke) that he (Obi-Wan) was a Jedi. That makes it seem like Luke had known about it before the start of episode IV.

Comment: @DavidZ I am not intimately familiar with the canon outside the films, but Luke refers to him as an "old hermit who lives beyond the Dune sea". Luke doesn't have big reaction when finds out his *father* was a Jedi and not "a navigator on spice freighter"...

Answer (score 65):

Imagine you grew up a farm boy in some podunk town in Backwater, Nebraska, where nothing ever happens. All your life you have never been further than 20 miles from the place you were born, and in that 20 miles there is nothing but corn. You are still in high school, and you realize your instructor used to be a Navy SEAL. And a secret agent. And walked on the moon. And advised the president. That is the level of excitement that Luke experiences when he learns who Ben is.

Things like Jedi and the Clone Wars, even though they are relatively recent events, they are distant enough from Luke's tiny existence to be legendary to him. Luke entering that larger world is a major part of the story of Star Wars. I don't think that audiences really appreciate that any more now that the prequels have been made.

Answer (score 55):

When Obi-Wan mentions Luke's father, Luke asks, "You fought in the Clone Wars?" to which Obi-Wan replies, "Yes, I was once a Jedi Knight, the same as your father." They then proceed to talk about what happened to Luke's father. Luke never mentions how long ago the Clone Wars were, nor even expresses much surprise that Obi-Wan was involved. Over-all, he takes the news quite well.
Here's a link to the clip.

It wouldn't really be surprising if Luke did think the Clone Wars were "so long ago." After all, when you've only been alive for 20 years, 20 years is a very long time. Most 20 year-olds today would say the '90s were "so long ago," too.

Comment: A good point. Personally I feel anything which happened on this planet before I was born feels long ago. And furthermore if you never experienced anything directly related to the war, it seems so much more away. Ever since he can remember (probably since he was 10-12 ?) The empire was solidly established, the single unshakable ruler of the whole galaxy with nobody to counter it (until some rebel vagabonds started something...)

Comment: Never noticed how close Luke comes to impaling Obi-Wan when he flicks on the saber for the first time! :)

Comment: Note, that the line *" It's all such a long way from here "* is in this clip at the 3:43 mark, but it's in reference to Obi-Wan's request that Luke help him go to Alderaan.

Comment: The real question is why Luke isn't surprised to find out Obi Wan was a Jedi Knight.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Phineas & Ferb probably mentioned to Luke that Old Ben was giving them Jedi lessons.

Comment: Consider that we have been at war since at least 2001. That's longer than the lifetime of most people reading this. "The Clinton Years" have a mythical smell (not altogether pleasant) nowadays. There is a book on these called "A Bubble in Time: America During the Interwar Years, 1989-2001", one could imagine Luke finding a book "A Bubble in Time: The Galaxy During the Interwar Years" and consider it about old history, but I digress...

Comment: I noticed that this answer was written by Aziri (with 331 rep and a blue icon) and edited by Aziri (with 113 rep and a black icon). Are you using 2 accounts?

Comment: Further to @Hack-R's comment, you can merge your two accounts by following the instructions [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Please do go ahead and do this; it'll make a lot of things much easier for you, including editing your own posts without needing your edits 'approved' by other people.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Thanks, Hack-R and Rand al'Thor, but I didn't see this until I'd solved the issue. See, I came over from Worldbuilding, where I had the first account (the one that edited) and answered the question here as an unregistered, then signed in. I just got that sorted out.

Answer (score 11):

It seems my memory played a [Jedi mind] trick on me: The quote "But that was so long ago" is actually from the novelization of the movie that was authored by George Lucas before the movie came out (which is weird - the movie opened at the end of May 1977, but the book was published in November 1976!). As @Rogue Jedi pointed out in his comment, it was really ghostwritten by Alan Dean Foster.

While most of the book is in line with the movie, and material from the book later became canon ('Senator Palpatine' is mentioned for the very first time here!), there are changes. This appears to be one of them - movie Luke seems only mildly surprised to learn of Obi-Wan's involvement in the C.W., and doesn't mention the time aspect at all.

For more on the book, including some of the ways it differs from the movies, see this link: [Star Wars: From the Adventures of Luke Skywalker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_From_the_Adventures_of_Luke_Skywalker)

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the fact that clone wars was quite a while before, and Luke is a young man, it is not unreasonable to expect that anyone left on the losing side of the war, would be dead. The Jedi were supposedly killed off, and Luke did not know Obi Wan was a Jedi at that point. The other major group of combatants - the clones - aged at double the normal rate and would be long dead, if they survived the war.

Comment: Uh - wars are not generally fought until the full extinction of one side, and clones that age naturally and were in their best fighting age 20 years ago should not be "long dead" now.

Comment: But this does raise an interesting follow-up question - how do you re-integrate genetically modified clone warriors into the workforce once your opposition is thrown down :) ?

Comment: @xLeitix. Well, somebody had to work on all those new construction projects.

Comment: @xLeitix Here's a page on this from worldbuilding.se http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/39191/what-can-the-government-do-with-its-clone-army-after-the-war-is-won

Comment: @xLeitix the empire did a pretty good job of hunting down all jedi, and most clones became part of the empire - essentially removing the entire Republic from the war. As shown in the Star Wars Rebels series, the advanced aging of the clones puts them as grey haired old man in that timeframe.

Comment: @xLeitix As for the clones, there are some wikia sources (and i believe a recent-ish book) that say that many clones became the first stormtroopers, wiped out on the death star I, and the rest were discharged into retirement. By my estimate, they would be 30-40 years old (aged at 60 to 80) years. Worth noting, there were multiple batches of clones over at least a 10 year period, if not close to 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider is the fact that the clone wars were mainly fought on core worlds, and mention of the war on outer rim worlds would have been rare. And wouldn't you be surprised if an old hermit under a bridge told you he was a WWII General?